# Plotting Partial Dependence Plots in R for binary target (mlr)

Tags: r, machine-learning, visualization, mlr

I have a problem to get partial dependence plots with mlr to work properly for me. Somehow not the probability is plottet, but just the class label. I suspect, that the target may be lost during the creation of der partialdependence-data.

Any ideas?

```
library(mlr)
library(dplyr)
library(ranger)

# select subset
iris_bin <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "virginica") %>% 
  mutate(bin_target = ifelse(Species == "setosa", TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  select(-Species)

# fit model
task_bin <- makeClassifTask(data = iris_bin, target = "bin_target")
lrn_bin  <- makeLearner("classif.ranger", predict.type = "prob")
fit_bin <- train(lrn_bin, task_bin)

# create partial dependence plot
pd <- generatePartialDependenceData(fit_bin, task_bin, "Sepal.Length")

pd  # is the target correct?
#> PartialDependenceData
#> Task: iris_bin
#> Features: Sepal.Length
#> Target: FALSE
#> Derivative: FALSE
#> Interaction: FALSE
#> Individual: FALSE
#>        FALSE Sepal.Length
#> 1: 0.4920347          4.3
#> 2: 0.4920347          4.6
#> 3: 0.4935947          4.9
#> 4: 0.4945947          5.2
#> 5: 0.5104600          5.5
#> 6: 0.5107800          5.8
#> ... (#rows: 10, #cols: 2)
plotPartialDependence(pd)
```

[image]

This would the details of my current session, maybe this helps?:

```
Session info ---------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.383)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  German_Germany.1252         
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2018-03-29                  

Packages ----------------------------------------------------
 package      * version    date       source                                   
 assertthat     0.2.0      2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 backports      1.1.2      2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 base         * 3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 BBmisc         1.11       2017-03-10 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 bindr          0.1.1      2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                           
 bindrcpp     * 0.2        2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 checkmate      1.8.5      2017-10-24 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 colorspace     1.3-2      2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 compiler       3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 data.table     1.10.4-3   2017-10-27 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 datasets     * 3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 devtools       1.13.5     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 digest         0.6.15     2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 dplyr        * 0.7.4      2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 ggplot2        2.2.1.9000 2018-03-26 Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@3c9c504)       
 glue           1.2.0      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 graphics     * 3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 grDevices    * 3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 grid           3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 gtable         0.2.0      2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 labeling       0.3        2014-08-23 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                           
 lattice        0.20-35    2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                           
 lazyeval       0.2.1      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 magrittr       1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 Matrix         1.2-11     2017-08-21 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                           
 memoise        1.1.0      2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 methods      * 3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 mlr          * 2.13       2018-03-28 Github (mlr-org/mlr@a9036e3)             
 mmpf         * 0.0.4      2017-12-05 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                           
 munsell        0.4.3      2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 parallel       3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 parallelMap    1.3        2015-06-10 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 ParamHelpers * 1.11       2018-02-19 Github (berndbischl/ParamHelpers@59c649e)
 pillar         1.2.1      2018-02-27 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 pkgconfig      2.0.1      2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 plyr           1.8.4      2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 R6             2.2.2      2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 ranger       * 0.9.0      2018-01-09 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 Rcpp           0.12.16    2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                           
 rlang          0.2.0.9001 2018-03-26 Github (r-lib/rlang@49d7a34)             
 rstudioapi     0.7        2017-09-07 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 scales         0.5.0      2017-08-24 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                           
 splines        3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 stats        * 3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 stringi        1.1.7      2018-03-12 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                           
 survival       2.41-3     2017-04-04 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                           
 tibble         1.4.2      2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 tools          3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 utils        * 3.4.2      2017-09-28 local                                    
 withr          2.1.2      2018-03-26 Github (jimhester/withr@79d7b0d)         
 XML            3.98-1.10  2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                           
 yaml           2.1.18     2018-03-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for -- I get a plot with the probability for the FALSE label on the y axis (from this you can get the probability for TRUE). What exactly do you want it to plot?

Comment: I tested your code and I receive the same result as Lars Kotthoff. mlr version 2.12.

Comment: Interesting... Just ran this snippet on my laptop and got a meaningful result (probability for class FALSE) on the y-axis. I use mlr version 2.12 on both machines and will check the other dependencies tomorrow. The approach via `pdp::partial()` also worked.

Comment: I suppose changing the plotted label (e.g. from FALSE to TRUE) would work like this: `pd$data <- pd$data %>% mutate(Class = TRUE, Probability = 1 - Probability)`? Or is there some argument that I have missed similar to `lime::explain`'s `labels`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff any further ideas? :)

Comment: What do you want to plot? I don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, the plot I added shows a constant value over all levels of the predictor, even though the pd object shows estimated differences. Not that useful, isn't it? If it would work, it would be nice to be able switch the (binary) prediction label, so the output can be interpreted easily.

Comment: I can't reproduce the output you're getting.

Comment: I added the output of the pd-object, which seems to be the cause of the confusion. It should have three columns and the name of the target column should be "bin_target" afaik. I updated R and Rstudio to the latest version as well as mlr, but the issue is still present...

(I may write a custom function to fix the output, but I'd rather get it to work using the defaults)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully the `mlr` package maintainers can help (I don't use that package). However, in the meantime, you can fit the model directly, and just use the `pdp` package:

```
fit <- ranger(as.factor(bin_target) ~ ., data = iris_bin, 
              probability = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(pdp)
pd <- partial(fit, pred.var = "Sepal.Length", prob = TRUE)
autoplot(pd)
```

Note the use of `prob = TRUE` in the call to `partial`. Also, `ggplot2` is not necessary as you can just use `plotPartial(pd)` instead, which relies on `lattice` graphics.

Also, you can still fit the model with `mlr` and then use `partial` on that; for instance,

```
library(mlr)
library(dplyr)
library(ranger)
library(pdp)

# select subset
iris_bin <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "virginica") %>% 
  mutate(bin_target = ifelse(Species == "setosa", TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  select(-Species)

# fit model
task_bin <- makeClassifTask(data = iris_bin, target = "bin_target")
lrn_bin  <- makeLearner("classif.ranger", predict.type = "prob")
fit_bin <- train(lrn_bin, task_bin)

# partial dependence plot
mod <- getLearnerModel(fit_bin)  # EXTRACT THE MODEL!!  <<--
partial(mod, pred.var = "Sepal.Length", prob = TRUE, 
        plot = TRUE, train = iris_bin)
```

Note, however, the need to supply the original training data via the `train` argument.